# AWS SDK for C++ のAws::S3::S3Clientで発生するSEH Exceptionについて

Tags: c++, aws, amazon-s3

お世話になります。
AWS SDK for C++ を使ってS3にファイルをアップロードする処理を書ています。

・コード

```
    bool hoge()
    {
   　　 Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
    　　config.region = "ap-northeast-1";

   　　 Aws::S3::S3Client　S3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials
           ("accesskey_id","secret_key", "session_token"), config);

    　　Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest objectRequest;
    　　objectRequest.WithBucket("bucket_key").WithKey("fileName");

    　　objectRequest.SetBody(fileData);

        auto putObjectOutcome = S3Client.PutObject(objectRequest);
　　　　　　 以下省略
}
```

コンパイルは通るのですが、実行した際に上のコードのAws::S3::S3Client S3Client(略)　というコンストラクタに差し掛かったところでエラーが出ます。

・エラー内容

```
初回例外が 0x00007FFCF4A7E48C (aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll) で発生しました (プロジェクト名.exe 内): 0xC0000005: 場所 0x0000000000000000 の読み取り中にアクセス違反が発生しました。
```

gtestを使ってテストを行っているのですが、そのときのエラーとしては

```
unknown file: error : SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.
```

が出てFAILEDとなります。

どうやらよくわからないメモリを参照しているようなのですが、原因が不明です。

呼び出し履歴を見るとcrtexe.cのCRTStartup() (626行目)からさらに多く呼び出しが
行われ、最終的に

```
testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<class testing::Test,void>(class testing::Test *,void ( testing::Test::*)(void),char const *)
```

というところで処理が止まります。

調べてみても良い解決策が見つからないため、こちらで質問させていただきます。
何かありましたら補足致します。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 既にご存知かもしれませんが、別の要因で出た同じようなエラーを aws-cpp-sdk-core を動的リンクするか静的リンクするかをプロジェクト全体と揃えると直るという投稿がありました。 ["AWS C++ SDK, SQS thows access violation"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40955351/5989200) -- Stack Overflow ／ ["SQSClient throws access violation when created"](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/357) -- GitHub issue

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。visual studioの設定上は全てダイナミックリンクになっているのですが、上記のエラーが出るということはexeに含まれていないということなのでしょうか。リンクについて理解が浅いためなぜ今回のケースで動的リンクが上手くいかないのかわかりません...とりあえず静的リンクで揃えられるか試してみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: AWS SDKの使用開始・使用終了処理を呼び出していなかったことが原因でした、ありがとうございました。

Comment: お疲れ様です。もしお時間ありましたら、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 承知致しました、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aws SDKの使用開始・使用終了処理を呼び出していなかったため起こったエラーでした。
使用開始

```
Aws::SDKOptions options;
Aws::InitAPI(options);
```

使用終了

```
Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```

これを追加することで、正常にアップロードが可能となりました。非常に単純な見逃しでした...
ありがとうございました。